# Write a trigger to save all modification on table Goods. (Update and Delete)

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement

When i try to run this code it give me this error : Errors: TRIGGER TRG1
Line/Col: 24/3 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

if

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg1
    BEFORE UPDATE OR DELETE
    ON GOODS
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE 
        lid INT;
        descrip VARCHAR(300);
    BEGIN
       descrip := CASE  
             WHEN UPDATING THEN 'UPDATE'
             WHEN DELETING THEN 'DELETE'
        END ;
        IF(:NEW.good_id IS NULL) THEN
            descrip:= CONCAT('Data for Good ID', CONCAT(:OLD.good_id, ' has been deleted from GOODS table.'));
            insert into goods(good_id,good_group_code,good_name,good_cost,note)values(1, 100,'group1', 100,'');
        ELSE
            IF(:NEW.good_id != :OLD.good_id) THEN descrip:= CONCAT(CONCAT(:OLD.good_id,' is updated to '), :NEW.good_id);
            ELSE IF(:NEW.good_group_code != :OLD.good_group_code) THEN descrip:= CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(' ',:OLD.good_group_code), ' is updated to '), :NEW.good_group_code);
            ELSE IF(:NEW.good_name != :OLD.good_name) THEN descrip:= CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(' ',:OLD.good_name), ' is updated to '), :NEW.good_name);
            ELSE IF(:NEW.good_cost != :OLD.good_cost) THEN descrip:= CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(' ',:OLD.good_cost), ' is updated to '), :NEW.good_cost);
            ELSE IF(:NEW.note != :OLD.note) THEN descrip:= CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(' ',:OLD.note), ' is updated to '), :NEW.note);
            END IF;  
            
            descrip:= CONCAT(descrip, CONCAT(' for good_id ', :OLD.good_id));
             insert into goods(good_id,good_group_code,good_name,good_cost,note)values(1, 100,'group1', 100,'');
    
        END IF;
    END
```

Comment: Please tag which RDBMS you are using (eg. SQL Server, Oracle, MySql, etc.)

Comment: Your final `end` is missing the trailing semicolon.  I assume that you actually mean `elsif` rather than `else if` in your `if` statement.  But taking a step back, I am not at all sure what your trigger is trying to accomplish.  Trying to do an `insert` into `goods` in a row-level trigger on `goods` doesn't make sense.  If you fix the syntax errors, you'll have coded an infinite recursive loop which will cause a runtime error.

Comment: Can you write the right code please